# IOS Distribute Error - No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any architectures in the bundle executable xcode 15

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I got this error when I tried to deploy my app to the App Store

> No architectures in the binary. Lipo failed to detect any
> architectures in the bundle executable

Everything ok and I can run my app on a simulator or device test, but when I try to archive it and deploy it on the server this error happens. I can archive but I can not distribute it to the app store.

I use XCode 15 to build RN projects, I also use an extension service NotifeeNotificationService .[image]

But If I remove the notifeeNotificationService it will distribute successful, I don't know why.

[image]

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Comment: I got "No architectures in the binary" Fault  same like your fault but I could not any solution